# sqlite update - issue

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have following code on the button which when clicked updates the fields based on a id value jobNumber. I am unable to understand why the DB is not getting updated. I would appreciate if someone could help me here:

What seem to be missing? Thanks in advance. Documents directory has 777 permissions and so the db file.

Code:

```
  -(IBAction)saveJob:(id)sender
   {
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement = NULL;
    const char *sql1 ="UPDATE JOB SET JOBTITLE =?, COMPANY=?, ADDRESS =?, PHONE=?     WHERE jobNumber=?";


    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql1, -1, &statement, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1,[self.jobTitle.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2,[self.Company.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3,[self.Address.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4,[self.phoneNumber.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 5,[self.jobNumber.text intValue]);
    sqlite3_exec(db, sql1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in updating data"); ====> Code always comes here. 
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(db);
```

I have another statement which inserts rows and it works. But update isn't

Answer (score 0):

You *must* check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql1, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"error...: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return ...;
}
```

Furthermore, you must not call `sqlite3_exec` on `sql1`.
Additionally, the `COMMIT` must be executed *after* the `sqlite3_finalize`, and is useless if you have not executed a `BEGIN`. (You *must* check `sqlite3_exec` for errors, too.)

Comment: Thank you. I will check and let you know how it goes.